# How to make devise gem go to specific page when the option 'Remember me' is ticked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So, a returning user in my app who has ticked "Remember me" has to land in a different page inside the app instrad of the home page and being logged in there.

I went through the documentation but i cant find a function that does this.

I also struggle into make devise go to a different page when the user updates the profile and i use wrong methods for this.  Can you give me the correct method and where to put it as well?

I tried using the method 'after_remembered' in my ApplicationController but it doesn't work while the method after_sign_in_path_for works!

Do i need to overwrite something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise sets a `remember_created_at` value for the user if "Remember Me?" is selected. In the `after_sign_in_path_for` you could have it check for `resource.remember_created_at` and then perform the redirect there.

A quick example would be in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  resource.remember_created_at ? path_for_remember : path_not_for_remember
end
```

To handle redirects after updates you want to use the `after_update_path_for` which is set up the same way:

```
def after_update_path_for(resource)
  some_path
end
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response but can you provide me with code for do this?

Comment: @hack-is-art added some examples

Comment: I get undefined method for resource.remember_checked_at?

Comment: Sorry. Meant to put `resource.remember_created_at`